# Android implementation with Realm DB, transactions on main UI Error

Tags: android, multithreading, transactions, realm

I am implementing an instance of the Realm Database within the android application I am designing. However, at first I got this error about Realm transactions on main UI thread:

```
Running transactions on the UI thread has been disabled. It can be enabled by setting 'RealmConfiguration.Builder.allowWritesOnUiThread(true)'.
```

I enabled the setting mentioned above, but the error persisted. I decided to implement an AsyncTask class in order to try to execute the realm transaction within the doinbackground method (which runs on a separate thread) but i am still getting the same error.

Can you offer me some advice on how I should proceed?

kind regards,
Lampros

Comment: Hi, I am getting the same error and I do not know how to enable that setting at all. Could you help me out?

Comment: Is there any update? I am also facing the same error.

Answer (score 4):

Are you actually building a Realm configuration object after you call `allowWritesOnUiThread(true)` and using it to retrieve your Realm instance?

Comment: Yes. After calling allowWritesOnUiThread(true), i am calling .build() also. Still the error showing.

Comment: @PrantikMondal did you get any solution?

Answer (score 3):

I know this is late but was able to resolve this by changing `realm.execute` to `realm.executeTransactionAsync` instead of setting `allowWritesOnUiThread(true)`.

Comment: Thank you, this solution was more helpful comparatively.